useMutation returning null onError
I am using Tanstack query to make a PUT request. I am observing a 500 response in the network inspector, but when I log out the error in the onError function it returns null.
(Edit: to clarify, I want there to be an error - that's what I'm trying to handle currently in the code. But I expect something to be returned, not null)
Why is this happening? The only thing I can see that is different about this request compared to the other ones that catch the errors successfully is I am passing an extra argument in at the mutationFn step - does the Promise need extra handling here?
const apiCall = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (payload) => apiRequest(id, payload),
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log("success handling done here")
    },
    onError: ({ error }) => {
      console.log("Error returns null here")
    },
  })


Whats the extra argument you are passing that makes this work correctly?

@sphnx It's the id you can see being given to the apiRequest. The api call needs it but it isn't part of the payload so it has to be passed separately. The other requests that are returning errors how I expect don't need the extra argument, but I'm not convinced that's the problem here

Well I use it the same way, the only difference being I don't make the callback to the mutate function async, can you try it out?

For anyone who runs into this, the problem in this case was that the request was returning a void response type (204 on success) so it needed a format param adding to decode the error correctly.

You should not destructure error from OnError
const apiCall = useMutation({
      mutationFn: async (payload) => apiRequest(id, payload),
      onSuccess: () => {
        console.log("success handling done here");
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error); // Logging the actual error
      },
    });


Thanks but I've tried this & the onError function captures an object that contains both data and error properties. Logging out the top level does not fix the null issue
